# Doctrine DBAL type boolean for SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've problems using type boolean in SQLite. The error-message is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException' with
>   message 'Unknown database type bool requested,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SqlitePlatform may not support it.'

The error happens on connecting to SQLite database. The database-schema is just the default from here: https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-generic-sqlite/

How can I solve this? I didn't find something on Google/Stackoverflow.

Comment: If you vote down my question please tell me why so that I can explain what's unclear and add missing informations! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Doctrine, so you should also use it to set up the database structure for you. So instead of running these "Create table" statements yourself, use the solution below, which applies to your use case.

If you're using **Doctrine ORM** set up your entity classes as described here: [Basic Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html)

If you're using **Doctrine DBAL** *without* the ORM, you should set up the database structure like this:
[Schema-Representation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-representation.html)

Comment: In general I'm with you, as this schema is different for every database-driver and mandatory by PowerDNS we won't provide it by our management software. Our Software doesn't change anything on this schema just checks that it exist.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SqlitePlatform API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Platforms.SqlitePlatform.html#180-186), boolean type is defined as 'BOOLEAN' (I am sure it is case insensitive) not 'bool'.